# jQuery 'taphold' does not fire, while 'tap' does

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, flutter, webview, dart

In my flutter app I have html inside a webview and some javascript with jquery attached. I want to trigger different actions depending on if a list item receives 'tap' or 'taphold'. I'm using jquery-mobile 1.5.0-rc1.

My javascript is as follows:

```
$('div.board').on('taphold tap', 'div.thread, div.thread-special', function(event) {
        console.log('event');
        var $item = $(this);  // The item that was clicked or held
        var scope = $item.data('itemscope');  // No numbered IDs! You can find everything about the item
        // etc.
        var type = event.type;
        if (type === 'tap') {
            console.log('tap');
        } else if (type === 'taphold') {
            console.log('taphold');
        }
    });
```

When I tap, I can see a 'tap' in the console. When I taphold, nothing at all happens or appears on the console. Any idea why?

Comment: Just FYI, by using only JQM this code works fine...

Comment: Hmm, thanks, it must be something else... But I'm running out of ideas :D